# Uniqueness of Projective Spectra for Ideals with Fixed Degree Generators

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

I am a beginner studying algebraic geometry on the level of Hartshorne. By Chapter II Exercise 2.14(c), the projective spectra $\mathrm{Proj}\,S$ can be isomorphic (as locally ringed spaces) to $\mathrm{Proj}\,T$ for non-isomorphic graded rings $S$ and $T$, as long as $S_d\cong T_d$ for all $d\ge d_0$, where $d_0$ is an integer. This seems a little surprising to me because it is very different from affine spectra.

I am curious if we can uniquely determine the rings $S$ or $T$, if we put restriction on the degrees of the generators. More precisely, let $R:= k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ denote a polynomial ring over a field $k$, with ideals $I,J\subseteq R$. If we assume that the ideals $I,J$ are both generated by homogeneous polynomials with a fixed degree (e.g., quadratic forms), do we necessarily have that $\mathrm{Proj}\,(R/I)\cong\mathrm{Proj}\,(R/J)$ implies $I\cong J$ (i.e., there exists an automorphism of $R$ under which $I$ and $J$ can be identified)? Any comment or reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Geometrically the point is that defining the homogeneous coordinate ring requires more structure than the bare projective variety; it requires a choice of (very ample) line bundle on this variety (then we take sections of tensor powers of it), and a given projective variety can have many different line bundles on it. That's the difference from the affine case.

Comment: I don't think you've asked the question you mean to ask; the corresponding statement for affine schemes is already false, since $I$ and $J$ could be related by a nontrivial change of coordinates. Did you mean $\text{Proj}(R/I) = \text{Proj}(R/J)$ (as subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^n$)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comments. For your first comment, I don't understand the line bundles very well yet, but I guess I would just need keep learning to understand that part. For the second comment, yes I meant $\mathrm{Proj}(R/I)\cong\mathrm{Proj}(R/J)$ as subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^n$, and I am curious whether we could have $R/I\cong R/J$ in this case of $I,J$ having fixed degree generators. I think this is true for the affine case since if we have $\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)\cong\mathrm{Spec}(R/J)$, then the global sections $R/I\cong R/J$ should be isomorphic as rings, implying $I=J$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just realize what you meant. The ideals $I$ and $J$ can be related by a nontrivial change of coordinates, so the best we can hope for is that $I\cong J$ under an automorphism of the ring $R$. Thank you for pointing this out and I have edited the question accordingly.